# Fetch data from Salesforce Calendar using Javascript

Tags: javascript, salesforce

What is the best way (or at least any way) how to fetch Events from the Salesforce Calendar ideally using JavaScript. I do not have any serverside processor available, nor possibility to install anything. Just a little background, I need this info to be fetched to Sharepoint, where I have the Webpage with JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from an API with this:

```
fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people/1")      // Return response promise.
.then((res) => res.json())                  // Return data and parse JSON.
.then((data) => console.log(data.name))     // Do something with data.
.catch((err) => err);                       // Catch error.

// Output is "Luke Skywalker"
```

Comment: thanks, but I would like to get the way for Salesforce platform :-) That is probably not that easy from outside of Salesforce